# Point Queue Model in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I am working on a simulation model, part of which requires having a point queue model that implements following equation:

```
dl1(t)/dt=max{q1(t)+q3(t)-C1,-l1(t)/Delta_T}
dl2(t)/dt=max{q2(t)-q3(t)-C2,-l2(t)/Delta_T}
```

I know to implement it I need having a function that takes q(t)'s as input and outputs into two separate state-space blocks to generate each l(t). Can anyone help please?

Comment: You don't want `state-space` blocks, you just need `integrator` blocks.  Just do a web search for something like "Simulink Tutorial" and you'll get any number of links to basic tutorials showing how to implement simple first order systems like this.

Comment: I used integrator block. and obtained result. Thanks!